# Detect HTTP sessions using tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump

I have a tracefile and I want to ﬁnd all web servers that were successfully visited in the trace, contacted via HTTP.

I'm using:

tcpdump -r file.trace - tcp  port 80

Maybe I have to search for a list of server IP that send response packets to me (I mean those that create HTTP sessions with me). Just servers, not other TCP connections. I mean, I need server IPs that answer to HTTP requests and send HTTP responses back.

Comment: What tools have you looked at to try filtering the dump file? What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is

```
  tcpdump -A -i eth0 -s0 host www.example.com and port 80
```

where you can leave out any of the above options:

```
  A resolve IP addresses 
  i bind to interface eth0
  s0 show full packet
  host is obvious
  port 80 show request and reply.
```

If you leave www.example.com out,

```
  tcpdump -A -i eth0 -s0 dst port 80
```

will show you all requests to port 80, like

```
  tcpdump -A -i eth0 src port 80
```

the replies. You may substitute -r file for -i eth0. Occasionally, remember you may have to use port 8080 instead.